# Create multiple tables in Sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I am creating 2 tables in a SQlite database:

```
create table [Files]
(
  Id int identity not null
    constraint PK_File_Id primary key,
  MimeType nvarchar (400) not null,
  Name nvarchar (280) null
);

create table [Languages]
( 
  Code nvarchar (4) not null
    constraint PK_Language_Code primary key,
  Name nvarchar (80) not null
    constraint UQ_Language_Name unique                   
);
```

When I run the query only the Files table is created. Why?

Comment: So, what is the error message?

Comment: No error message. But only the first table is created

Comment: How exactly are you running the two statements?